# User is not adding in the members

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a GroupApp and I am trying to add some group members in premium_members(`ManyToManyField`).

**The Problem :-**

BUT When i click on `add_premium_member` in the group's post's User. Then post creater is not adding in `premium_members`. No error is showing. BUT NOT ADDING.

models.py

```
# For Group Creation

class Group(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
    premium_members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='premium_members', blank=True)
```

urls.py

```
    path('add_premium/<int:pk>/', views.add_premium, name='add_premium'),
```

views.py

```
# For add post creater in premium_members.

def add_premium(request,pk):
    group = get_object_or_404(Group,pk=pk)
    user = get_object_or_404(User,pk=pk)
    group.premium_members.add(user)
    return redirect('home')
```

**Traceback**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/add_premium/3/
Raised by:  app.views.add_premium
```

I have tried many times by changing instance name and `get method` but nothing worked for me, Still not adding user with no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a user added to a group you need to do something like this

group_detail_view.html

```
<b>Post Creater :</b> {{ post.user }}<a href="{% url 'add_premium' user.id data.id %}">Add to Premium Members</a>
```

Here your passing data as the context object of the group instance. You could also get the id for the group from post.group.id (instead of data.id)
Next lets adjust the views..

```
def add_premium(request,pk, group_id):
    try:
        group = Group.objects.get(pk=group_id)
    except Group.DoesNotExist:
        group = Group.objects.create(title='New Group')
    user = get_object_or_404(User,pk=pk)
    group.premium_members.add(user)
    group.save() # add this
    return redirect('home')
```

get_object_or_404 is conveient but can be tricky. You might not acutally want to raise a page not found, but instead create a group that the user SHOULDbe apart of. It seems like the logic here is that a user SHOUUL ALWAYS be apart of a group, so 404 would be bad.

Now for urls..

```
    path('group_detail_view/<int:pk>/', views.group_detail_view,name='group_detail_view'),

    path('add_premium/<int:pk>/<int:group_id>/', views.add_premium, name='add_premium'),
```

Now we have updated the urls to look for both the user id and the group id

Comment: Try doing post.user.id.  instead of user.id in your html. I think the user is automatically a context object, so it might be access the user initiating the view. Another way to check is simply displaying the user.id in the html. "Page Not Found" because there is an issue with the URLs. Can you display your URl config?

Comment: It is showing `id` correctly BUT When i put `post.user.id` in `url` then it is saying **Page Not Found(404)**

Comment: can you display your URL patterns?

Comment: The url your passing to in the anchor tag is `add_premium`. Where is that? Your current configuration is sending a GET request to the url named add_premium with the user.id appended.

Comment: Your redirecting 'home' with no url named home. You need to add a home view or redirect elsewhere.

Comment: I have a page named home. AND if i remove it then it is still showing **PAGE NOT FOUND**

Comment: Can you provide the complete traceback?

Comment: This is an update for using regex but still thecomplete traceback would really help. With all the urls that django checked at least. It gives you a list of all the URLs it searched. Here is the regex you might want to try re_path(r'add_premium/(?P<pk>[0-9])$', views.add_premium, name="add_premium") Also dont forget, from django.urls import path, re_path.

The reason why Im wondering if its the order of the urls

Comment: I did according you said, BUT still showing the same error.

Comment: Take a screenshot so we can see all the URLs it searched. Or copy and paste the whole thing.

Comment: Wait its finding the pattern. `add_premium` Are you sure a group exists? Your using `get_object_or_raise_404`incase an object is not found. Your looking up a group with the same pk as the User. Make sure the group with pk 3 exists.

Comment: You need to figure out how the group will be determine. If the group isnt created and you want to immediately create one you can use get_or_create. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/
If you want to send the group id via URL, then you need to readjust the URL pattern. But at least you know your code is working perfectly as you have deisgned.

Comment: I updated my answer. This is more what your looking for. If you still want to raise a 404 you can remove the try and except and keep the `get_object_or_404` but leave the views params as I have listed. Dont forget to upvote!

Comment: Sorry for late Reply, BUT It is still not adding in `premium_members`. BUT you did a good job of passing two ids. Thank  for your Time and effort. I cannot upvote because i don't have enough reputation but i marked as accepted answer